# Encoding and decoding Binary Tree into/from String?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I'm looking for an efficient way to encode a Binary Tree into a single string, and an efficient (recursive?) way to decode a string back into the original Binary Tree. Presumably the encoding would use some sort of delimiting method to mark left/right children and backtracking.

Any known methods to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could transverse the tree in pre order starting by the root. Saving the value of every note in the string seperated by a comma in that progress. Additionaly you need to mark every leaf, for the encoding.